# TeamCity deployment in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

How to create autodeployment in Tomcat with TeamCity. I used container deployer but it always says me filed to deploy.

```
    [Step 6/8] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/home/aecktann/JetBrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/f8bcef79481c6bb2/target/ChatBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
, root cause is org.codehaus.cargo.container.*******.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path /ChatBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
[16:41:40]  [Step 6/8] Step TomcatDeployer (Container Deployer) failed
```

Comment: There is no information that can help to understand the problem you have. By deployment to Tomcat you mean putting WAR file to Tomcat directory? Or what? From that point of view deploying is just copying WAR file.

Comment: I want that after any changes in my repository on my git server teamcity will make deploy in tomcat. And I will see evrything in my host

Comment: Ok. you're configuring VCS Root and Trigger to catch changes in the repo. Then TeamCity builds your artifacts (WARs). Then you just perform a copy operation to upload your WARs to the directory with Tomcat that you should know. That is what gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't look like the deploy failed, so not jenkins, it might be the actual app not starting, have you done a manual deploy with the same jenkins user? might be a permission issue also.

Answer (score 0):

I'am fix this problem. Problem was in Spring servlets and Tomcat didn't compile

```
Step 1/1: Deploy to localhost (Container Deployer)
[15:49:12]
[Step 1/1] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create deployable with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.TomcatWAR for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x]], deployable type [war]).
, root cause is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\BuildAgent\work\81266a51f2e66bcc\11 (The system cannot find the file specified)
[15:49:12][Step 1/1] Step Deploy to localhost (Container Deployer) failed
```